# Finding the Cardinality of a Cartesian Product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> **[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5Pr7.png)**: $$A=\{ 1,2,3, \dots, n \}$$ $$\text{ Find the Cardinality of ... } $$$$\{(a,S) | a \in S, S \in P(A)\}$$

So the way I've approached this problem thus far was to find the cardinality of $S$ and then multiply it by the cardinality of $a$. If I'm not mistaken the cardinality of $S$ should be $2^n-1$ as $S$ cannot be an element of itself and the cardinality of $P(A)$ is $2^n$. However, I'm having difficulty finding the cardinality of $a$. Is it just n? And if so, why is that?

Comment: Can you define $P(A)$?

Answer (score 0):

As $S$ is a subset of $A$, $a\in S$ is an element of $A$, and consequently talking about its cardinality doesn't make much sense. I'll provide some hints only since this might be a homework question. Let $T$ be the set about whose cardinality you inquire.

---

**Example:** Let's fix $n:=3$ for now. Then

$$\mathcal{P}(A)=\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},A\}.$$

In this case we have

$$T=\{(1,\{1\}),(2,\{2\}),(3,\{3\}),(1,\{1,2\}),(2,\{1,2\}),(1,\{1,3\}),(3,\{1,3\}),(2,\{2,3\}),(3,\{2,3\}),(1,A),(2,A),(3,A)\}$$

and consequently $\operatorname{card}(T)={3\choose 1}+2{3\choose 2}+3{3\choose 3}=12$.

---

**Hint:** Observe that in the example above I listed the elements of $T$ using a somewhat natural ordering of its elements. First I ordered the nonempty subsets of $A$ (which are the nontrivial elements of the power set of $A$) according to their cardinality, and then I used the natural ordering of the natural numbers to order the pairs $(a,S)$ (for fixed $S$). In terms of cardinalities, then, computing the cardinality of $T$ is nothing but counting the cardinality of the power set of $A$, except one should use the cardinality of each subset as a weight, so that a subset of $A$ with $k$ elements should contribute not $1$ but $k$ to the total count.

---

**Hint 2:** Continuing from the previous hint, there are (at least) two ways to give an answer. Either you can generalize the formula for $n=3$ and show that it is correct for arbitrary $n$ using induction, or you can try to write $T$ as a disjoint union of sets whose cardinalities are much easier to compute. Following the ordering used above, a nonzero subset of $A$ can have at least $1$ element and at most $n$ elements. But how many subsets of $A$ are there containing $k$ elements, for $1\leq k\leq n$?

---

As a further exercise, it might be instructive also to think about what happens when $A:=\Bbb{N}$.

Comment: Okay, so this is what I have so far...  $S \in P(A)$ and $a \in S$. Since $S \subseteq A$ and $a \in S$ therefore $a \in A$. This would mean that $\vert a \vert = n$

Comment: What do you mean by $\vert a\vert$?

Comment: As in the cardinality of a. So basically what I'm trying to say is that the cardinality of a must equal n

Comment: What is the cardinality of a natural number?

Comment: So let's say $A = \{1,2\}$ then if $a = 1$ then S would either be {1} or {1,2} and if $a = 2$ then S would either be {2} or {1,2}. In each case the cardinality of S = $2^n-1$ as there are $2^n-1$ sets which satisfy $a \forall a$

Comment: Then when we look at $T$ it would just be $n2^n-1$ correct?

Comment: Oh so you are first fixing $a$ and then counting the number of subsets $S$ that contain $a$? That should work as well, but you are overcounting the number of subsets that contain a fixed $a$. For instance in your example you count $4$ elements in $T$ (which is correct) but your formula gives $7$.

Comment: Ooops I mean $n2^{n-1}$